# How to set background to old color when use onmouseout javascript

Tags: javascript

When `onmouseover` div will change background to `black`, and when `onmouseout` i want to change background to old color in this case is red by not specify red color in code how can i do ?

```
<style type="text/css">
.test {
    background: red;
}
</style>
<div onmouseover="onmouseover_fn()" onmouseout="onmouseout_fn()" class="test" id="test">TEST</div>

<script>
function onmouseover_fn(){
    document.getElementById("test").style.backgroundColor = "#000000";
}

function onmouseout_fn(){
    document.getElementById("test").style.backgroundColor = "unset";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use css pusedo class [**:hover**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover)

```css
.test {
  background: red;
}

.test:hover {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="test" id="test">TEST</div>
```

Comment: Oh , sorry for my Stupid sir.

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is tagged with `javascript`, you can use `classList.add()` and `classList.remove()` functions:

```js
function onmouseover_fn(){
    document.getElementById("test").classList.add('black');
}

function onmouseout_fn(){
   document.getElementById("test").classList.remove('black');
}
```

```css
.test {
  background: red;
}
.black{
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div onmouseover="onmouseover_fn()" onmouseout="onmouseout_fn()" class="test" id="test">TEST</div>
```